# Maruti Suzuki Swift Dzire VXi - Gear Shifting trouble - Across All Gear shifts

Tags: clutch, suzuki, shifting, gears, maruti

I have a Maruti Suzuki Swift DZire VXI 2013 model. I am experiencing problems during gear shift when the car is in motion. And the problem starts to happen only after i have drove for like 7-10 kms(during which the shifting is relatively smooth). After the 7-10 km mark, shifting the gear is really difficult. Sometime I have to forcefully push the lever when i want to get into 1st. I asked a service technician and he suggested that i would have to replace my entire clutch system. I wanted to check if anyone else has faced the same problem and if yes, what did you do to sort this out.

Any help in this regard is much appreciated.!

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!